# C# Dynamic IEnumerable <class>

Tags: ienumerable

Anyone know how to pass the `IEnumerable<xxxxx>` into method. `XXXXX` is refer to any class.
I want to make it dynamic to accept any class. Example, `<student>`, `<course>`, `<semester>`, etc.
Currently it is fixed as Employee class.

```
public IEnumerable<Employee> GetJsonFile(string strFolder, string strFileName)
{
      string strFile = Path.Combine(WebHostEnvironment.WebRootPath, strFolder, strFileName);
      using (var jsonFileReader = File.OpenText(strFile))
      {
        return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Employee[]>(jsonFileReader.ReadToEnd(), new JsonSerializerOptions { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true});
      }
}
```

Comment: Example <student>, <semester>, <subjects>, etc

Comment: use Generics. Enumerable<T> Where T is a class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `<Employee>` use `<T>`

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetJsonFile<T>(string strFolder, string strFileName)
{
    ...return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T[]>...
}
```

Then when you call the method you supply it with the type.

```
var x = GetJsonFile<student>(folder,file);
```

For more information lookup [information on C# Generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/).

Comment: I able to solved now. Thank you very much for the guideline.

Comment: How to apply the same thing for web API?  
Original code:
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<Employee> Get()
        {           
            return GetJson.GetJsonFile<Employee>("Data", "employee.json");          
        }
    }
}
 
After change to following, no data is return.Why?

[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<T> Get<T>()
{
   return GetJson.GetJsonFile<T>("Data", "employee.json");          
}

Comment: Why did you change the WebAPI Version?

Comment: I have 2 versions. 1 in Service (solved guided by you, thank you)  and another 1 in Web API Controller. Now I facing issue in Web API controller. I want to do the same as in Service.

Comment: You need to `T` to something 
`public  IEnumerable<employee> GET() {return GetJson.GetJsonFile<employee>("Data", "employee.json"); } `

Answer (score 1):

Use Generics. `IEnumerable<T>` Where T is a class.
[Generics Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/)